# Left, Right and Center Align Child div under Parent Div Container

Tags: html, css

I want to align child Div under my Parent Div based on its class to left, right or Center.

I have done the following,

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:1px;
  width:100%;
  margin:1px;
}

.left-item{
  float:left;
  padding:auto;
  margin:1px;
}

.center-item{  
   padding:auto;
  margin:1px;
 }

.right-item{
 float:right;
 padding:auto;
  margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">        
    <button class="left-item">Left</button> <button class="center-item">Center 2</button> <button class="right-item">Right</button> <button class="left-item">Left</button> <button class="right-item">Right</button> <button class="center-item">Center 1</button> <button class="center-item">Center 3</button>        
</div>
```

I am unable to **align** `child Divs` to center to parent `Divs`. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Try `float:left` on the center-item too

Comment: are you mad?... @PrasunJajodia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give text-align:center property to container div.
JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/72aqsq83/1/

```
.container{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:1px;
  width:100%;
  margin:1px;
  text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A simpler way to divide a box into left, center and right is using CSS flexbox. By wrapping left, center and right in a new `div` and turning your container into a flexbox with `display:flex` you are able to emulate this behavior with much less code.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button>Left</button>
    <button>Left</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Center 2</button>
    <button>Center 1</button>
    <button>Center 3</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Right</button>
    <button>Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i would like to use CSS class so that i don't restrict my html template  to  have only three Child divs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the CSS flexboxes properties.
This would probably solve your problem :

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

To learn more about the Flexbox properties, here are some link I recommend:
[MDN - Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
[MDN - flex-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)
[MDN - justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

The CSS flexible boxes are easy to use, and fully supported :
[CanIUse - "flexbox"](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)